# custom Toggle button in android

Tags: android, custom-controls, togglebutton

I have added a custom toggle button and it works fine.
the issue is that for toggle button enable and disable.
I need a different layout for button on ,button off ,button on & disabled ,button on & enabled ,button off & disable and button off & enabled.
Here is code for on / off.
How to do ??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_pause_pressed"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_play_pressed_new"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </item>        
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do that before, but since the *StateList* is a drawable, it might be possible to reference another XML-File, containing a *selector*.

This would look like this...
**button.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled"/>

    <item android:drawable=@drawable/button_disabled/>
</selector>
```

**button_enabled.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_pause_pressed"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_play_pressed_new"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</item>        
</selector>
```

The **button_disabled.xml** would look like the **button_enabled.xml**, but containing the looks for the the disabled Button..